# Android Dex: the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message

Tags: java, android, dex

I'm trying to compile simple Android project with SlidingMenu (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in IntelliJ Idea 12, but I'm having this trouble:
[image]

I've got only this Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Test");
        // set the content view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // configure the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: @kelorek If I remember, error was somewhere alse. If you got it, try to follow instructions in warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Including (swith on) FLAG in IDE compilation setting (Android Compilers): 
  Add "--core-library" flag

will resolve this problem